# Not valid for storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb

I get the error:

> The dollar ($) prefixed field '$size' in 'analytics.visits.amounts..$size' is not valid for storage.

```
return Manager.updateMany({},
        {
            $push: {
                "analytics.visits.amounts": {$size: "$ips"},
                "analytics.visits.dates": new Date()
            }

        }
).exec()
```

What I try to do is I have an array called `ips` and I have another array `amounts` and I try to push the size of `ips` into the amounts array

The structure of a single document is:

```
{
    offices: [{
       ips: []
    }],
    analytics: {
        visits: {
            amounts: [],
            dates: []
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal update syntax can not use document variable values, meaning the `$ips` is what's throwing you the error.

For Mongo v4.2+ they introduced [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which allows you to use document values in an update, like so:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "analytics.visits.amounts": {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$analytics.visits.amounts",
          [
            {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$offices",
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {
                  $sum: [
                    {
                      $size: "$$this.ips"
                    },
                    "$$value"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "analytics.visits.dates": {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$analytics.visits.dates",
          [
            new Date()
          ]
        ]
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tu5EYFpYJtc)

If you're using an older Mongo version then you will have to read the documents into memory in order to fetch the `ips` values to use in the update.

Comment: thank you for the answer. i have made a mistake in my question could you take a look? the `ips` array is actually in the `offices` array. i need to sum the sizes of all `ips` and then add it to the `amounts` array

Comment: I edited in the fix, you can easily use this using `$reduce`.